# Binding onChange Event to jHtmlArea textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

How do I bind an onchange event to this  jQuery [plugin](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/07/21/jHtmlArea-The-all-NEW-HTML-WYSIWYG-Editor-for-jQuery.aspx) .
I want to save the content the user types in this textarea . So I will bind an onchange event and post on ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually wrote a jQuery plugin to solve this issue . This jQuery plugin , takes an element and watches if the user has entered some data , by accessin the elements keypress and keyup elements .
Have a look at the plugin [here](http://sanandnarayan.com/editable/index.html) and its source is up on [github](https://github.com/sanandnarayan/Editable-Jquery-Plugin)

Please let me know if you have any queries :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can always change jHtmlArea's updateTextArea function to trigger a change event like so.

```
updateTextArea: function() {
    var value = this.toHtmlString();
    this.textarea.val(value);
    this.textarea.change();
},
```

When there is a change handler on the original textarea then it'll get triggered. You may need to tweak this a bit it'll get you started at least.

Comment: Thank you, but it makes jhtmlarea unacceptably slow on my machine